# Why can't you change srcCompat of an Imageview directly?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am following the Kotlin Android tutorial and am currently on the Dice Roller App tutorial. For changing the image, the tutorial says to write:

```
diceImage.setImageResource(drawableResource)
```

My question is, why can't we change the image directly? Like say:

```
diceImage.srcCompat = drawableResource
```

I thought that maybe the reason we couldn't do that was that the srcCompat variable was private, but later the tutorial writes:

```
diceImage.contentDescription = diceRoll.toString()
```

The content description is under the same "common attributes" tab as srcCompat, which probably means srcCompat isn't private. Although I'm probably wrong.

My questions are:

Why can't we set srcCompat directly?

What is the setImageResource function doing exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the ImageView, the actual image is a Drawable.  When you setImageResource, you're setting an int id.  The ImageView will then look up what Drawable is associated with the id by calling context.resources.getDrawable(id) and save that in a variable.  So you can't just do it via a property set, because the value you'd be storing isn't the same type as the value you'd be setting it to.  Thus you need a function.

Notice there are several different ways you can set the image on an image view-  from a Drawable, a resource id, a Bitmap, etc.  If you have more than one way, it needs to be a function and not a property.  ContextDescription can work because you're only ever setting it to a CharSequence.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer! But just as a clarification question, srcCompat is a private variable right? Is that why we can't access it?

Comment: srcCompat doesn' exist.  That's an XML attribute.  It isn't a variable in the class, and the class is free to handle it any way it wants-  which may be setting it to a variable, or may be setting a dozen variables.  srcCompat in particular was made to be a wrapper around src, adding in additional capabilities that weren't possible to backport for various reasons.  But XML attributes do not need to map to variables or properties in the class directly.

Comment: When the function saves context.resources.getdrawable(id) in a variable, what happens next? Does it interact with the XML attribute src to change the image?

Comment: It invalidates itself and forces a redraw.  The XML no longer exists at that point-  the xml is only used to create it initially.